# Do I have a better option than CopyOnWriteArrayList and Collections.synchronizedList?

Tags: java, android, synchronization, thread-safety

In my app I've been using an ArrayList for a while, and now I need to be able to access it from different threads. I'm doing lots of read and lots of write. This list is a private member of a class, and I have a getter to access it from other classes.

Just replacing my `ArrayList` by a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` works, but I'm affraid by the performance loss (my list contains GPS coordinates updated every 2 seconds, and I'd like it to work as long as possible).

Using `Collections.synchronizedList` also works if I wrap every access to the list's getter in a `synchronized() {}` block, which means that I have to go through all the app code to check.

I tried to:

- declare my getter as `synchronized`
- wrap the `return myList;` of my getter in a synchronized block

But both lead to `ConcurrentModificationException` when reading the list while writing it.

Is there a better option than `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or adding `synchronized() {}` blocks everywhere?

If it matters, this is an Android app.

EDIT: here's some code illustrating my two tentatives using the getter:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> mList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

public ArrayList<MyObject> getList() {
    synchronized(this) {
        return mList;
    }
}

public synchronized ArrayList<MyObject> getList() {
    return mList;
}
```

EDIT 2: here is more information about the use case, following @Martin Marconcini comments:

- the app can load KML files (files containing features like markers, lines & polygons) on a Google Map
- I have a Map class having ArrayLists holding references to every loaded feature. That class has a load(Feature f) method that will load the given feature to the Google Map and store it into the suited ArrayList (either markers, lines or polygons list).
- I have a KmlFileLoader class parsing KML files
- I have a KmlFile class having ArrayLists holding references to every feature of the file (which can be loaded on the map or not). That class have a loadOnMap(Map map), which will call map.load(Feature f) for every feature. This is where the ConcurrentModification happens: if I'm accessing the map's features while loading a file to it.

In fact, there are not that much places in my code where I iterate the lists outside the Map class, so fixing the problem for this project with synchronized blocks is much easier than what I thought originally. Inside the map classe, I had already made all the methods accessing the lists synchronized, so there's no problem here (I do not even need to use Collections.synchronizedList, as I'm synchronizing on the Map object).

But I'm still interested to know if there's a better option than using CopyOnWriteArrayList and wrapping my getters into synchronized blocks. I guess not.

Comment: Probably. You haven't described what the meaning of this data structure is.

Comment: "wrap the return myList; of my getter in a synchronized block" it's unclear what you mean here: do you mean you out a synchronized block inside the getter? If so, that's only synchronized until the getter returns. (Same for making the getter synchronized).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Well the class is a KML file loader, having Markers, Polylines & Polygons lists (so I have multiple lists in fact). When loading a big file in the background, I still want to be able to read / write these lists.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, that clarifies why the synchronized block / declaration does not work. Is there a better option than checking in all the app / using CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Comment: You need to decide what's more important: Getting the absolute latest copy when you do get, or getting a relatively up-2-date version that may have received updates in the last few seconds, but are not that important becaus you will get them "in two or three seconds again". I'd argue that regardless of the implementation and blocking protections, the question goes beyond this scope. Is this data/structure (that you haven't shown) the correct approach? Who is responsible for this synchronization? Why do you have this problem to begin with? :)

Comment: I'd separate the fetching/parsing/storing of your "big data file" as its own problem. You cannot access that until it's done. this is your "Use Case", likely accessed from your MyObjectRepository. Now the repo can elect to push intermediate results as chunks, this is fine, but then have the repo publish said intermediate results as they are ready. Then any app can observe them and fetch them at will (and safely). You can even have a getter, but again, you cannot avoid the copy here, you want to return immutable stuff to your UI anyway...

Comment: Lastly, by watching this problem, I believe you're trying to prematurely optimize it. First make sure your architecture is as simple and robust as possible, then identify problems that may be simplified or broken down into more performant code. Separating network/parsing, vs. storage, vs. publishing/accessing for read are three different problems and should never interfere with each other. Your UX receives immutable lists I hope, so copy what you have at the time of the request. (And because this is Android, you can use LiveData at the end of the chain to offer the results).

Comment: Thanks @MartinMarconcini, please see my 2nd edit. I don't think refactoring the code to use LiveData or other would be worth it, there are not that much places in the code where I need the synchronization.

Comment: @TimAutin I just saw your edit. In that case, I'd say stick with the synchronization blocks (use a final lock if needed) and measure if it's worth any other change, beyond having to refactor the interfaces to handle concurrency in a different way. As far as I know, your best bet is what you're doing now, at least until you decide to modify the architecture (which, like you said, would be a pain for little gain). :) Let's see if another bigger brain can add more info. Apologies for not having a better answer (it's also late for me)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Yes that's what I also think. Thank you very much for your time, good evening!